# Is there a modification of Laplace's method for obtaining the asymptotic behaviour of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals?

Tags: asymptotics, stieltjes-integral, laplace-method

Is there a modification of Laplace's method for obtaining the asymptotic behaviour of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals?

In particular, I am interested in asymptotic behaviour of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$L(x)=\int_{0}^{T} te^{-xt} \text{d} g(t)$$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$, where $g$ is a nondecreasing function. Or at least an upper bound for $L(x)$, which is sharper than stemed from the mean value theorem, $L(x)=O(1/x)$.

Comment: This would more like be a generalisation of Watson's lemma.